# What's have better performance and memory usage: guava sets or java 17 set?

Tags: java, guava, java-17

I have a big runtime HashSet collections: How i can use memory effective? Which tools or libraries i need? Big collection this is from 1000 - to 1000000 elements. Colections count from 4 to ~20;

I'd try to use initial capacity for decrise a count of resize of hashmap for perfomance.
May be have some libraries as guava (not sure that use this is right) or something else for decrise memory usage, or have some comparing "some library" vs java17 - memory/performance

Answer (score 2):

> What's have better performance and memory usage: guava sets or java 17 set?

If you are talking about `java.util.HashSet`, and the objects returned by Google Guava's `Collections.newHashSet()` they are the same class and (therefore) have the same performance and memory characteristics.

See https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java line 180.

---

If they were different classes, I would recommend that you write a *representative* benchmark and compare the performance and memory utilization of the alternatives for yourself.  Note that overall performance of collection types often depends on how you use them; e.g. the sequence of operations that you perform, and how well you have implemented `hashCode` and `equal` for the element types.  Make sure that you do the benchmarking with *your* classes, and that the usage patterns correspond to what your real application will do.

Also note that if your `initialCapacity` estimate is poor, you can actually make performance and memory usage worse.